# Convergence test of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show whether the series converges or diverges.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1+5^n}{1+6^n}$$
Justify the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$ \frac{1 + 5^n}{1+6^n} = \frac{1}{1+6^n} + \frac{5^n}{1 + 6^n} \leq \frac{1}{6^n} + \frac{5^n}{6^n}$$

Comment: So by comparison test they are all converge?

Comment: No, not "they all": yours is, as **you know** (hopefully) that the right hand series converges...

Comment: well since $$0 \leq \frac{1}{1+6^n} \leq \frac{1}{6^n}$$ it converges and $$0 \leq \frac{5^n}{1 + 6^n} \leq \frac{5^n}{6^n}$$ it also converges. thus since addition of converges series is converges, the original series converges. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing directly:

$$\frac{1+5^n}{1+6^n}\le\frac{2\cdot 5^n}{6^n}=2\left(\frac56\right)^n$$

Comment: basically this method is the simpler version of the previous example but you are using the same theorem right?

Comment: Yes indeed. Isaac's solution majorizes the given series with two convergent ones and I do thesame with only one.CHoose whatever you prefer better.

Comment: Nice, just want to get used to the comparison test. thanks

Comment: how about for example the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{n^2}$$ I can do this $$0 \leq \frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n}$$ but the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{n}$$ diverges and suppose the original series converges. How do i compare this?

Comment: You can do that comparison but it won't help you at all. Either you majorize with a convergent series or you minorize with a divergent one. In your case, you majorize the series of $\;1/n^2\;$ with the *divergent* harmonic series of $\;1/n\;$ , so...nothing: you can't deduce anything at all.